# mongodb: how to filter out the records that created today?

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection with a timestamp field of type datetime.now():

```
"chashi_ts" : ISODate("2012-06-12T16:08:22.645Z")
```

With only mongodb commandline, how to find the records that the field's datetime points to today?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming you can get the current date....

```
// the start of the day (midnight)
begin_date_range = ISODate("2012-06-12T00:00:00Z");

// the start of the next day (at midnight)
// this can also be done with 11:59:59PM of the current date using $lte
end_date_range = ISODate("2012-06-13T00:00:00Z");

results = db.collection_name.where({"chashi_ts":{
              "$gte":begin_date_range,
              "$lt":end_date_range}
          );
```

Comment: there is no db.collection_name.where() method in mongodb

Comment: It should be - results = db.collection_name.find({"chashi_ts":{
              "$gte":begin_date_range,
              "$lt":end_date_range}
          );