# Mongo: Querying for only today's document using Node

Tags: node.js, mongodb

How do I query MongoDb for only today inserted Documents? My documents look like this

```
{
    "_id" : "8Mj3s6GRkvNeftbAP",
    createdAt: ISODate("2016-02-10T07:51:08.934Z"),
}
```

I tried `{"createdAt": new Date()}` which is not working probably due to time stamp. Please help

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11380428/mongodb-how-to-filter-out-the-records-that-created-today

Comment: hey hi , i need to dynamically  generate date rages please help

Comment: where you got blocked?

Comment: i want to create a current date ISODate object which starts from 12 Am so that query will bring all the objects which are inserted today and this must be dynamic as this script will  run every day

Comment: Data.now gives you the current date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you query the collection for documents with `createdAt` equal to `new Date()` i.e. the current timestamp, you won't likely to get any result because the `createdAt` field will have values less than the current timestamp as time
passes.

What you need is to query a date range that encompasses today, not the current date time. In other words, create a date object that represents that start of today, with that you can then query your collection for documents
that have the `createdAt` field greater than that date. A mongo shell example follows:

```
var startOfToday = new Date();
startOfToday.setHours(0,0,0,0);

db.collection.find({ "createdAt": { "$gte": startOfToday } });
```

The above will query the collection for documents created today.